# Maven update resets Java version

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Everytime I modify the dependencies inside the `pom.xml` file in my IntelliJ Maven project, the Java version is set to `1.5` and I have to receonfigure my project.

The following settings are modified by Maven:

`Settings` | `Compiler` | `Java Compiler` -> `Target bytecode version`

[image]

And  `Project Settings` | `Modules` -> `Language Level`

[image]

Why is this happening and what do I have to do, so that maven doesn't vandalise my settings?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to explicitely set the java version in your pom file so that version 1.5 doesn't get set by default.

```
<project>
 [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: I have this set in all of my pom.xml files and it still resets it to bytecode 1.5 and language level 5. something else is going on but not sure what that is

Answer (score 5):

Specify the java version under `properties`.

```
<properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
</properties>
```

and to use the same version with maven compile or package then include the same version in compile plug-in

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: the maven-compiler-plugin version is important, I missed that piece and it didn't work until I changed that.